# What is p_start in scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to understand the different arguments of scipy.optimize package

```
x_start = 3.0 * np.ones(len(t))
# bounds on the values :
bounds = tuple((0,20.0) for x in x_start)
constraints = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun':  lambda x, s_0=s_0: 
constraint_1(x, s_0=s_0)},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun':  lambda x: constraint_2(x)},
    {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, a=a, b=b: constraint_3(x, a=a, b=b)})
opt_results = optimize.minimize(objective, x_start, args=(a, b, d, t), method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
```

please explain me the `x_start` and `bounds` arguments used in the `optimize.minimize` command and how I can change `x_start` and `bounds` according to a different set of data.

Comment: read this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

- `x_start`: Initial guess. Array of real elements of size (n,).
- `bounds`: Bounds on variables for `SLSQP` and trust-constr methods. `None` is used to specify no bound. SLSQP stands for Sequential Least SQuares Programming.

There are two ways to specify the bounds:

- Instance of Bounds class like [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.Bounds.html#scipy.optimize.Bounds).
- Sequence of (min, max) pairs for each element in x.